Help in calculating the following infinite product
$[
\lim_{{n \to \infty}} \cos \frac{\pi}{2^2} \cos \frac{\pi}{2^3} \cdots \cos \frac{\pi}{2^n}
]$
I know the answer should be $2/π$ but stuck otherwise. Thought about using series expansion and logarithms.
